# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory' - registry item

Tags: powershell

I am retrieving a path from the registry, example below:

```
$registry = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\ClientSetup\"
($path = Get-ItemProperty -Path $registry).Path
$path = Split-Path -Path $path
```

This is ok, now I want to return only directories at this location

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory
```

Running this line shows the error `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory'`.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You are using Get-ChildItem in the context of Registry Provider, not filesystem, are You sure that idt does support `-Directory` switch in this context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Registry Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/registry-provider?view=powershell-6) doesn't support `-File` and `-Directory` like the [FileSystem Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider?view=powershell-6). They are dynamic parameters added by the provider to the standard `Get-ChildItem` set. See the *Dynamic Parameters* sections of my previous links.